# Where is "keyboard-keys-from-name.h" used by udev of systemd of Linux?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, systemd, udev

`keyboard-keys-from-name.h` is referred to by `udev-builtin-keyboard.c`, which is a part of the source code of udev of systemd of Linux.  It appears on an `#include` directive in `udev-builtin-keyboard.c`.

```
#include "keyboard-keys-from-name.h"
```

However, `keyboard-keys-from-name.h` does not come with tar balls of systemd.  For example, the tar ball from the following link does not contain `keyboard-keys-from-name.h`:
https://codeload.github.com/systemd/systemd/tar.gz/v233

Where is `keyboard-keys-from-name.h`?

Note that I exclude locations unofficial to udev or systemd.
For example, the LFS team provides their own copy of `keyboard-keys-from-name.h` with their LFS version of udev-lfs at
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/infoburp/udev-lfs/master/keyboard-keys-from-name.h". I exclude this LFS version from answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is generated inside the systemd source tree. See [`Makefile.am`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/Makefile.am):

```
src/udev/keyboard-keys-list.txt:
        $(AM_V_at)$(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
        $(AM_V_GEN)$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -dM -include linux/input.h - < /dev/null | $(AWK) '/^#define[ \t]+KEY_[^ ]+[ \t]+[0-9K]/ { if ($$2 != "KEY_MAX") { print $$2 } }' > $@

src/udev/keyboard-keys-from-name.gperf: src/udev/keyboard-keys-list.txt
        $(AM_V_GEN)$(AWK) 'BEGIN{ print "struct key { const char* name; unsigned short id; };"; print "%null-strings"; print "%%";} { print tolower(substr($$1 ,5)) ", " $$1 }' < $< > $@

src/udev/keyboard-keys-from-name.h: src/udev/keyboard-keys-from-name.gperf
        $(AM_V_GPERF)$(GPERF) -L ANSI-C -t -N keyboard_lookup_key -H hash_key_name -p -C < $< > $@
```

This means `keyboard-keys-from-name.h` is generated from `keyboard-keys-from-name.gperf`, `keyboard-keys-from-name.gperf` is generated from `keyboard-keys-list.txt`, and `keyboard-keys-list.txt` is generated from the system's `linux/input.h` (likely `/usr/include/linux/input.h`, which includes `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h`, where the `#define KEY_*` this generation series is looking for are.)